# Implementing multiple iterators in generic class - c# - IEnumerable(T)

Tags: c#, generics

In the following class, I have implemented succesfully IEnumerable(T) in order to iterate through T. In the same class I was able to implement IEnumerable(DLLItem(T)) to iterate through DLLItem(T). Both are working independantkly. It's probably a basic question. What should I do to have both iterators working together in the same class ?
I've tried several possibilities getting always compiler errors...

With IEnumerable(T)

```
public class DLL<T> :   IEnumerable<T>
{
    ...
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
    ...
        yield return ...
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

with IEnumerable(DLLItem(T))

```
public class DLL<T> :   IEnumerable<DLLItem<T>>
{
    ...
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
    public IEnumerator<DLLItem<T>> GetEnumerator()
    {
    ...
        yield return ...
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In advance, thanks for your support...

---

Solution as suggested by @dasblinkenlight (see below)

---

```
public class DLLItemEnum<T> : IEnumerable<DLLItem<T>>
{
    DLL<T> dll;
    public DLLItemEnum(DLL<T> d)
    {
        dll = d;
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
    public IEnumerator<DLLItem<T>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        ...
            yield return ...
        ...
    }
    public static explicit operator DLLItemEnum<T>(DLL<T> d)
    {
        DLLItemEnum<T> i = new DLLItemEnum<T>(d);
        return i;
    }
}
public class ItemEnum<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    DLL<T> dll;
    public ItemEnum(DLL<T> d)
    {
        dll = d;
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        ...
            yield return ...
        ...
    }
    public static explicit operator ItemEnum<T>(DLL<T> d)
    {
        ItemEnum<T> i = new ItemEnum<T>(d);
        return i;
    }

public class DLL<T> 
{
     ...
}
class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...
        foreach (int i in (ItemEnum<int>)z)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        foreach (DLLItem<int> i in (DLLItemEnum<int>)z)
           Console.WriteLine(i.Data);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show a use scenario for such an arrangement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Multiple Iterators is possible in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754041/is-multiple-iterators-is-possible-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` is shared among all generic `IEnumerable` objects, you cannot implement them both in the same class. You have two options in making it work:

- Provide two properties, `EnumerableItem` and `EnumerableDllItem`, that produce different iterator objects, the way suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1754048/335858), or
- Make separate `IEnumerable` classes - `ItemEnumerable<T>` and `DllItemEnumerable<T>`. Do not implement `IEnumerable` in `DLL<T>` at all, and provide two conversion operator from `DLL<T>` to `ItemEnumerable<T>` and to `DllItemEnumerable<T>`. Users would be able to decide on what iterator to use by inserting a cast.

Comment: Hi, I did it the second way you mentionned and it works as expected. Thanks to all people answering.

Comment: @CSJNL Great! If everything works and you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution, consider accepting the answer to indicate that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible, but it will be messy to use.

You have to implement both the `IEnumerable<DLLItem<T>>` and `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces:

```
public class DLL<T> :   IEnumerable<DLLItem<T>>, IEnumerable<T>
```

The `GetNumerator` methods will collide, so you would have to resort to explicit interface implemenation, which forces the caller to cast the object to the right interface type before accessing the enumerator:

```
var dllItems = ((IEnumerable<DLLItem<T>>)someDll);
var Ts = ((IEnumerable<T>)someDll);
```

My recommendation is to not go that way. Instead expose properties for one or both of the enumerators. Look for example at the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class. It implements `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` and exposes a `Values` property of type `IEnumerable<TValue>` and a `Keys` property of type `IEnumerable<TKey>`.

Answer (score 0):

In general prefer composition over inheritance.

The following class is easy to ceate and to use:

```
public class DLL<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Need to implement");
    }

    // Compose, not inherit
    public IEnumerable<DLLItem<T>> DLLItems
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Need to implement");
        }
    }
}
```